# What is the best service for cross-browser screen shots?

Tags: cross-browser

I have a website that I'd like to monitor for display problems in various browsers (mainly Internet Explorer.)  I know that browsercam.com and broswershots.org provide this as a service.  Could anyone recommend the best way/service to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used browsershots.org. Internet Explorer is very populair and there are long waiting lists for IE versions. Most of the time you will not see your screenshot before your 30 minutes will expire. 
You can try www.litmussapp.com. They have software which checks css.

oeps typo: it should be [www.litmusapp.com](http://www.litmusapp.com)

Comment: thanks for the tip.  litmus is pretty slick compared to other options (although there's definitely some room to improve.)  I signed up for a paid account today.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Adobe Browserlab](https://browserlab.adobe.com), even though it's annoying that you have to create an Adobe ID to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Theres also Microsoft SuperPreview and our new service, [Browsera](http://www.browsera.com).  One issue we faced with browsershots is that it scrolls the window to collect the screenshot, resulting in abberations if you have fixed positioned elements, or background images that don't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the Total Validator Pro Desktop Tool and do everything in one big shot.  Validation, WCAG, Screen shots, etc.  The online version lets you do one screenshot at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As most options in this question are no longer around I would like to suggest the [cross browser testing solution BrowseEmAll](http://www.browseemall.com) which can be used for testing (especially IE) desktop and mobile browsers.